# How to update a line chart using the stepper value?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I have a simple a*x+b exaple of Line chart.

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lineChart: LineChartView!

@IBOutlet weak var bStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var aStepper: UIStepper!

var aValue: Double = 1
var bValue: Double = 1

var dataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    aValue = aStepper.value
    bValue = bStepper.value

    updateChartData()
}

@IBAction func aChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    aValue = sender.value
    updateChartData()
}

@IBAction func bChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    bValue = sender.value
    updateChartData()
}

func updateChartData() {
    lineChart.noDataText = "No data"
    for i in -10...10 {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: aValue*Double(i)+bValue)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    let lineFuncOne = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: nil)
    lineFuncOne.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    let chartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineFuncOne)
    lineChart.data = chartData
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

I want to create method which updates the Line Chart (a*x+b) with values of a and b Stepper every time i increment or decrement value of steppers in my app. Can you help me to create this solution? I've started my journey and stopped with that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by myself
putting the 
var dataEntries = ChartDataEntry 
into updateChartData() and operating on a, b values from sender insinde updateChartData()